# "Let me write it down/write your name down/write down it/write down your name"

Tags: sentence-construction

Please tell me if all of the followings are correct, and more importantly, I would like an explanation.

A Let me write it down;

B Let me write your name down;

C Let me write down it;

D Let me write down your name;

And please explain it rather than just give me an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Let me" doesn't affect any of these sentences so I will ignore it in my answer.

"Write down" is a seperable phrasal verb. This means that the object can go in the middle or at the end. However, if using a pronoun, it must go in the middle.

A: "write it down" - 'It' is the object. 'It' is a pronoun. Pronouns must go in the middle. 'It' is in the middle. This is correct.

B: "write your name down" - 'Your name' is the object. 'Your name' is not a pronoun, so can go in the middle or at the end. This is correct.

C: "write down it" - 'It' is the object. 'It' is a pronoun. Pronouns must go in the middle. 'It' is at the end. This is **incorrect**

D: "write down your name" - 'Your name' is the object. 'Your name' is not a pronoun, so can go in the middle or at the end. This is correct.

See: https://www.insegnanti-inglese.com/grammar-1/phrasals-sep.html